# Triple integration $\iiint_E\dfrac{z}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} dV$ over a region defined by half of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2z$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate 
>   $$\iiint_E\dfrac{z}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} dV$$
>   where $E$ is the solid which lies above the plane $z = 1$ and inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2z$.

For this I got pi/3 but the answer key says (2pi/15)(16 - 3(2)^0.5).
I used spherical coordinates, 0 to 1 for rho, 0 to 2pi for theta, and 0 to pi/2 for phi. The answer key used sec(phi) to 2cos(phi) for rho, 0 to 2pi for theta, and 0 to pi/4 for phi.

Comment: Well, you have the key and answer.

Answer (score 2):

The area lies between $z=1$ and the sphere, then it lies between
$$\rho\cos\phi=1$$
and
$$\rho^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=2z=2\rho\cos\phi$$
which shows 
$$\dfrac{1}{\cos\phi}\leq\rho\leq2\cos\phi$$